# Django Email services

Tags: python, django, mailchimp, django-email

Want to integrating Email service with Django using Mailchimp.

I want to essentially use mailchimp for all email communications - new user registration on the site, forgot password etc.

What I want to do is something like -

1.Setup a specific email in mailchimp, such as the 'forgot password email'
When a user forgets their password, I want to trigger mailchimp to send the specified mail

Does anyone have experience doing the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides several views that you can use for handling login, logout, and password management. You have to check documentation: [Authentication Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).
Then you can use them like here:
[How to Use Django's Built-in Login System](http://How%20to%20Use%20Django's%20Built-in%20Login%20System) or [How to Create a Change Password View](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/04/django-tip-9-password-change-form.html)

I know that your are asking about mailchimp but check this:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/05/27/how-to-configure-mailgun-to-send-emails-in-a-django-app.html
Here you have nice tutorial how to configure Mailgun to send emails in a Django project.

ps. great django [blog](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/) check it out!